# An adjective for a film or book with very long dialogues

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word to describe a film (or book) that features very long dialogues and most of its scenes or passages revolve around dialogues? I came up with the word "dialogue-y" but that obviously doesn't exist. Ideally, the best answer would be a single word, but a phrase or expression will do too.

Thank you very much

Comment: "Tedious" comes to mind.  (Though I assume you're talking about *monologues* more than *dialogues*.)

Comment: How about a hyphenated word? For example, "dialogue-driven." "My Dinner With Andre" is definitely a dialogue-driven film.

Comment: It is a *wordy* film, tout simplement.

Comment: It sounds like a stereotypical *soap opera*.

Answer (score 2):

The adjectival form of 'dialogue' (variant spelling is 'dialog') is

> **dialogic** also **dialogical**, *adj.*
>    pertaining to or characterized by dialogue.

[dialogic. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved January 25 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dialogic ]

Thus, aside from technical senses of 'dialogic' ('dialogical' is a variant spelling), a *dialogical* novel, for example, is a novel dominated by dialogue, whether by weight or by volume.

An example from the wild, with reference to a novel:

> Spanish novelist Delibes (The Hedge, Five Hours with Mario--a monologue) here uses a series of psychiatric interviews to make a spare, **dialogical** novel.

(From a review of ["*THE WARS OF OUR ANCESTORS* By Miguel Delibes"](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/miguel-delibes-3/the-wars-of-our-ancestors-2/), in *Kirkus Reviews*, 1992.)

Another example, with reference to film:

> Today's films of counter-information are distinguished by an extensive arsenal of stylistic devices: self-criticism, bluff, irony, wit, the view of events from the periphery, the letter form, **dialogical** film forms.

(From ["Filmic Counter-Information: A Few Highlights from Film History"](http://www.republicart.net/disc/representations/tode01_en.htm), 2003, at the *Republic Art* site. By Thomas Tode, translated by Aileen Derieg.)

For extended and technical senses of 'dialogic', and an outstanding work generally, see [*The Dialogic Imagination*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/029271534X), by Mikhail Bakhtin.

Answer (score 2):

- ***Verbose/ Wordy***

  > using or containing more words that are needed (according to Oxford dictionary)
- ***Long-winded***

  > continuing for too long and therefore boring

Comment: I've removed question marks :)

Answer (score 0):

The dialogues were verbose or prolix.

Answer (score 0):

Fans of French cinema might be inclined to describe exceedingly wordy films as **Rohmeresque**, after the great [Éric Rohmer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0006445/), in most of whose movies practically nothing happens outside the conversations of the characters. A Google Books search turns up two dozen unique matches for *Rohmeresque*, going back to this one from [*The New York Times Film Reviews*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oaQLAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Rohmer%27s+Claire%27s+Knee,+which+was%22&dq=%22Rohmer%27s+Claire%27s+Knee,+which+was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBvsjQksbKAhUBH2MKHQTJC4kQ6AEIHzAA) (1975) [snippet]:

> Until this point, "Femmes au Soleil" is, as the festival program describes it "**Rohmeresque**," at least to the extent that it recalls the mood and the wit of Eric Rohmer's "Claire's Knee," which was ...

Not all of these sources use *Rohmeresque* in the same sense, but this example, from Rob Stone, "[Between Sunrise and Sunset: An Elliptical Dialogue Between American and European Cinema](https://books.google.com/books?id=0CpaCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA227&dq=%22rohmeresque%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG35TqkcbKAhVN4mMKHX21CYAQ6AEIQDAG#v=onepage&q=%22rohmeresque%22&f=false)," in *World Cinema's 'Dialogues' With Hollywood* (2007), seems entirely on point:

> In its apparently aimless nonconformism, *Slacker* exhibits the cool flavour of the French New Wave in its structure, characters, and themes. The debt to French cinema is especially evident in its platform for insouciant Godardian monologues delivered rhetorically but with no specific audience in mind, and intense **Rohmeresque** dialogues in search of meaning.
>
> ...
>
> *Before Sunrise* often contextualises Jesse and Céline amongst a collage of couples and characters who resemble the protagonists of intimate **Rohmeresque** dramas and there are even moments of what might be affectionate parody, when, much like Belmondo and Aznavour emulating Bogart because they have seen too many films noirs in *Breathless* (*À bout de souffle* 1960) and *Shoot the Pianist* (*Tirez sur le pianiste* 1960) respectively, Jesse and Céline, who may have seen too many French films, seem to fill pauses in the conversation by thinking of what a character in a film by Rohmer might say next.